# c# WindowsForms Form halt when updating multiple series in one chart

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm just starting to use VS2022, but I have a problem with something that seems really simple.
I'm trying to display multiple Series in Real time. It works fine with just one Series, but when I try to add more, it just halt after the some milliseconds. I don't get any error message and also can't interact with anything in the window, I'm not even able to move or resizes it.

I don't have the space to make them in individual charts

the code I used is this
Update: It's a mess but here is all my code

```
using GeoCoordinatePortable;
using GMap.NET;
using System.Data;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Timer = System.Windows.Forms.Timer;

namespace BaseStation_Cervus1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapControl gMapControl;

        private SerialPort myport;
        private string in_data;

        double x;

        int indexV = 0;
        List<double> alt = new List<double>();
        List<double> temp = new List<double>();
        List<double> pres = new List<double>();
        //List<double> aX = new List<double>();
        //List<double> aY = new List<double>();
        //List<double> aZ = new List<double>();
        //List<double> gX = new List<double>();
        //List<double> gY = new List<double>();
        //List<double> gZ = new List<double>();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            port_cb.Text = "COM5";

            gMapControl = new GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapControl();
            gMapControl.MapProvider = GMap.NET.MapProviders.GMapProviders.GoogleSatelliteMap;
            gMapControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            gMapControl.MapProvider = GMap.NET.MapProviders.BingMapProvider.Instance;
            GMap.NET.GMaps.Instance.Mode = GMap.NET.AccessMode.ServerAndCache;
            gMapControl.ShowCenter = false;
            gMapControl.MinZoom = 1;
            gMapControl.MaxZoom = 20;
            gMapControl1.Controls.Add(gMapControl);
            gMapControl.Position = new PointLatLng(29.16, -111.01);
            gMapControl.Zoom = 15;
            gMapControl.Update();
            gMapControl.Refresh();
            var markersOverlay = new GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapOverlay("You");
            var marker = new GMap.NET.WindowsForms.Markers.GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(29.16, -111.01), GMap.NET.WindowsForms.Markers.GMarkerGoogleType.purple);
            markersOverlay.Markers.Add(marker);
            gMapControl.Overlays.Add(markersOverlay);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick;
            timer1.Interval = 50;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myport = new SerialPort();
            myport.BaudRate = 9600;
            myport.PortName = port_cb.Text;
            myport.Parity = Parity.None;
            myport.DataBits = 8;
            myport.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            myport.DataReceived += Myport_DataReceived;

            try
            {
                if (!myport.IsOpen)
                {
                    myport.Open();
                    MessageBox.Show("Connected Successfully");
                    textBox1.Text = " ";
                    timer1.Start();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                myport.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Connection has closed, try again");
            }
        }

        private void Myport_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                in_data = myport.ReadLine();
                this.Invoke(new EventHandler(displaydata_event));
                SaveData();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error!");
            }
        }

        private void SaveData()
        {
            var foundIndexes = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < in_data.Length; i++)
            {
                if (in_data[i] == '/')
                    foundIndexes.Add(i);
            }
            try
            {
                int range1 = foundIndexes[1] - foundIndexes[0];
                int range2 = foundIndexes[2] - foundIndexes[1];
                int range3 = foundIndexes[3] - foundIndexes[2];
                int range4 = foundIndexes[4] - foundIndexes[3];
                int range5 = foundIndexes[5] - foundIndexes[4];
                //int range6 = foundIndexes[6] - foundIndexes[5];
                //int range7 = foundIndexes[7] - foundIndexes[6];
                //int range8 = foundIndexes[8] - foundIndexes[7];
                //int range9 = foundIndexes[9] - foundIndexes[8];
                //int range10 = foundIndexes[10] - foundIndexes[9];
                //int range11 = foundIndexes[11] - foundIndexes[10];
                temp.Add(Convert.ToDouble(in_data.Substring(foundIndexes[0] + "/".Length, range1 - "C/".Length)));
                pres.Add(Convert.ToDouble(in_data.Substring(foundIndexes[1] + "/".Length, range2 - "Pa/".Length)));
                alt.Add(Convert.ToDouble(in_data.Substring(foundIndexes[2] + "/".Length, range3 - "m/".Length)));
                var markersOverlay = new GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapOverlay("Rocket");
                var marker = new GMap.NET.WindowsForms.Markers.GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(Convert.ToDouble(in_data.Substring(foundIndexes[3] + "/".Length, range4 - "/".Length)), Convert.ToDouble(in_data.Substring(foundIndexes[4] + "/".Length, range5 - "/".Length))), GMap.NET.WindowsForms.Markers.GMarkerGoogleType.blue);
                markersOverlay.Markers.Add(marker);
                gMapControl.Overlays.Add(markersOverlay);
                //aX.Add(Convert.ToDouble(in_data.Substring(foundIndexes[5] + "/".Length, range6 - "/".Length)));
                //aY.Add(Convert.ToDouble(in_data.Substring(foundIndexes[6] + "/".Length, range7 - "/".Length)));
                //aZ.Add(Convert.ToDouble(in_data.Substring(foundIndexes[7] + "/".Length, range8 - "/".Length)));
                //gX.Add(Convert.ToDouble(in_data.Substring(foundIndexes[8] + "/".Length, range9 - "/".Length)));
                //gY.Add(Convert.ToDouble(in_data.Substring(foundIndexes[9] + "/".Length, range10 - "/".Length)));
                //gZ.Add(Convert.ToDouble(in_data.Substring(foundIndexes[10] + "/".Length, range11 - "/".Length)));
            }
            catch
            {
                label3.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { label3.Text = "Noise"; }));
            }
        }

        private void displaydata_event(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.AppendText(in_data + "\n");
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (indexV < alt.Count && alt.Count > 0)
            {
                //alt, temp, press
                chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(x, alt[indexV]);
                chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(x, temp[indexV]);

                if (chart1.Series[0].Points.Count > 100)
                    chart1.Series[0].Points.RemoveAt(0);

                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = chart1.Series[0].Points[0].XValue;
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = x;

                //aceleration
                //chart2.Series[0].Points.AddXY(x, aX[indexV]);

                //if (chart2.Series[0].Points.Count > 100)
                //{
                //    chart2.Series[0].Points.RemoveAt(0);
                //}

                //chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = chart2.Series[0].Points[0].XValue;
                //chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = x;

                //rotation
                //chart3.Series[0].Points.AddXY(x, gX[indexV]);

                //if (chart3.Series[0].Points.Count > 100)
                //    chart3.Series[0].Points.RemoveAt(0);

                //chart3.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = chart3.Series[0].Points[0].XValue;
                //chart3.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = x;

                indexV += 1;
                x += 1;

            }
        }
    }

}
```

I tried adding values to another Serie

```
if (indexV < alt.Count && alt.Count > 0)
            {
                //alt, temp, press
                chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(x, alt[indexV]);
                chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(x, temp[indexV]);                

                if (chart1.Series[0].Points.Count > 100)
                    chart1.Series[0].Points.RemoveAt(0);

                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = chart1.Series[0].Points[0].XValue;
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = x;

                indexV += 1;
                x += 1;

            }
```

but it halts, so I tried removing also the points of before.

```
if (indexV < alt.Count && alt.Count > 0)
            {
                //alt, temp, press
                chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(x, alt[indexV]);
                chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(x, temp[indexV]);            

                if (chart1.Series[0].Points.Count > 100)
                    chart1.Series[0].Points.RemoveAt(0);
                    chart1.Series[1].Points.RemoveAt(0);

                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = chart1.Series[0].Points[0].XValue;
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = x;

                indexV += 1;
                x += 1;

            }
```

but it still halts.
Let me know if you need more of the code

Update:
I separated the code for the chart, but it works fine.
I suppose is something else, it's really weird.

```
    using System;
    
    namespace TestChart
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
    
            double x;
    
            int indexV = 0;
            List<double> alt = new List<double>();
            List<double> temp = new List<double>();
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                timer1.Start();
                timer2.Start();
            }
    
            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick;
                timer1.Interval = 50;
                timer2.Tick += timer2_Tick;
                timer2.Interval = 10;
            }
    
            private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (indexV < alt.Count && alt.Count > 0)
                {
                    //alt, temp, press
                    chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(x, alt[indexV]);
                    chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(x, temp[indexV]);
    
                    if (chart1.Series[0].Points.Count > 100)
                        chart1.Series[0].Points.RemoveAt(0);
    
                    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = chart1.Series[0].Points[0].XValue;
                    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = x;
    
                    indexV += 1;
                    x += 1;
                }
            }
    
            private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                alt.Add(3 * Math.Sin(5 * x));
                temp.Add(3 * Math.Cos(5 * x));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If the app freezes then that suggests either a method doesn't return or you enter an infinite loop. You need to debug your code to find out which, or if it's something else. Where EXACTLY is that code? If it's in a loop in an event handler then it will monopolise the UI thread and the UI will not be able to be updated. The fact that it works for one series seems odd, but without additional context, we can't really say much more.

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly. If you have to create a new test project in order to isolate the relevant functionality for the example, that's what you do.

Comment: If the application just hangs, use "break all" in the debugger and check what the threads are doing. Chances are you have some kind of infinite loop, or are overwhelming the UI threads with messages of some kind.

Comment: Update: I added all my code and also a code to test the charts.

Comment: Too many Invoke() calls, it will freeze the UI when the main thread is overwhelmed with handling them.  Reduce the rate by collecting data in a List so you can Invoke() less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

As someone commented I made a list

```
        List<List<double>> allData = new List<List<double>>();
        List<double> rdata = new List<double>();
```

that let me save the data a lot simpler, but I had to change the format. And also instead of calling a function I just put this after I read the data.

```
        rdata = in_data.Split('/').Select(s => Convert.ToDouble(s)).ToList();
        allData.Add(rdata);
```

then I just had to indicate the column

```
            if (indexV < allData.Count() && allData.Count() > 0)
            {
                //alt, temp, press
                chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(x, allData[indexV][2]);
                chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(x, allData[indexV][0]);

                if (chart1.Series[0].Points.Count > 100)
                    chart1.Series[0].Points.RemoveAt(0);

                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = chart1.Series[0].Points[0].XValue;
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = x;

                indexV += 1;
                x += 1;
            }
```

it works well.

Comment: Your answer is helpful, you can mark it so that it can help more people